# Load a xgboost model in python which was saved by `xgboost::save()` in R

Tags: python, r, xgboost

I have a xgboost .model file which was generated using `xgboost::save()` in R. Now, I want to load  this and use it in python.

Comment: which package you used? How is it saved in R?

Comment: what gives `str(xgboost.model)` in R for an output? Can you post the code for generating that ind of model in R?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim, It was developed using xgboost package

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim, here is the output from str(xgboost.model)                            
 $ handle:Class 'xgb.Booster.handle' <externalptr> 
 $ raw   : raw [1:2699669] 00 00 00 80 ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "xgb.Booster"

Comment: so using which command you saved it? - the str looks like as if it contains the weights under $raw and a $handle ...

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim xgb.save()

Comment: I know this isn't what you want to hear, but you could save the parameter fits and fit a new xgboost model in Python. It saves some time.

Answer (score 3):

This does not appear to be possible (edit: in the standard python xgboost libary) due to an inability of the python implementation to load models from bytestring, a bug according to [this github thread](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3013)

A comment in that thread provides a workaround function, using the xgboost.core library:

```
import ctypes
import xgboost
import xgboost.core

def xgb_load_model(buf):
    if isinstance(buf, str):
        buf = buf.encode()
    bst = xgboost.core.Booster()
    n = len(buf)
    length = xgboost.core.c_bst_ulong(n)
    ptr = (ctypes.c_char * n).from_buffer_copy(buf)
    xgboost.core._check_call(
        xgboost.core._LIB.XGBoosterLoadModelFromBuffer(bst.handle, ptr, length)
    )  
    return bst
```

If you read in your binary file with something like:

```
with open('xgb_model.model','rb') as f:
    raw = f.read()
```

you should be able to load from the bytestring with:

```
model = xgb_load_model(raw)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you saved your model using `xgboost::save("/path/to/file")` in R, then the model is saved in `xbgoost-internal binary format`,
which can be read-in by Python's `xgboost` package.

First, install in Python by:

```
pip install xgboost
```

or if you are a conda user like me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

Then, load into Python by:

```
import xgboost
from xgboost import Booster

booster = Booster()
model = booster.load_model("/path/to/file")
```

Other ways of saving in R (`saveRDS()`) wouldn't allow easy transfer into Python.

Comment: Tired this but it say AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute 'load_model'

Comment: I got a similar error , basically that model object that we load using booster.load_model ('model' in the ex above) is of NoneType.